# pd.Timestamp changing month and day field when day <=12

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

I'm doing some data analysis using Pandas in a Jupyter notebook and analysing minute by minute data for a 2 year period. There's about 740,000 rows of data pulled in from a csv file (pd.read_csv('file location'))

Format of date_time: "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm" - i.e. 11/01/2017 21:52

Here's something weird I've found, when day<=12, the day and month switch, when the day is 13 and above the format is correct (when put through pd.Timestamp)

An example:

```py
pd.Timestamp("13/02/2018 02:26")

--> Timestamp('2018-02-13 02:26:00')
```

As you'd expect. Now taking it to 11th February:

```py
pd.Timestamp("12/02/2018 02:26")

--> Timestamp('2018-12-02 02:26:00')
```

Really unsure why this happens, would really appreciate some help on how I can avoid this happening.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Check with `to_datetime` and `dayfirst`

```
pd.to_datetime("11/02/2018 02:26",dayfirst=True)
Out[22]: Timestamp('2018-02-11 02:26:00')
```